# Pairwise wilcoxon-mann-whitney?

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Is there something like a pairwise version of the wilcoxon-mann-whitney test, i.e. the version of the pairwise Wilcoxon signed rank test, but with alternative hypothesis?

I don't seem to be able to find any information on such a thing, neither on the web, nor in hypothesis testing handbooks.

Maybe there is no special paired version of the wmw and even if the data is paired, using wmw is fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pairwise data, you are typically testing hypotheses about the differences, correct? If so, the Wilcoxon signed rank test on the *pairwise differences* is a good test to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I have been not clear enough in the description. I understand that Wilcoxon signed rank is a good test for my scenario (comparing differences), but as far as I understand it does not allow to specify any alternative hypothesis. Hence it always tests against the null whether the ranks changed, but not into which direction right?

Comment: @user2842189 the common use is as a two-sided but you can also get one sided tests for this. Basically, you compute the value of the signed rank statistic $T^+$ and test: $T^+ \leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-t_{\alpha}$ for a lower tail test and $T^+\geq t_{\alpha}$ for an upper tailed test, with $t_{\alpha}$ being the value of the test statistic such that P(Type I error)$=\alpha$.

Comment: @user2842189 here is a good explanation: https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~wild/ChanceEnc/Ch10.wilcoxon.pdf

Comment: Thanks. That helps. Talking about one-sided vs. two-sided, this general note might be of interest: http://www.bmj.com/content/309/6949/248

Comment: @user2842189 thanks! this is very interesting. I totally agree with their general conclusion: One-sided hypotheses are riskier because you are effectively ignoring 1/2 of the hypothesis space. thanks for the link.